# Trigger a cloud function to send a note if it isn't called within some long time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an IoT device that only sends data to the cloud (Google cloud function) infrequently.  The data includes a time stamp.  Once I turn off or I loose internet connection for the IoT device, I can't send a shut down notice to the cloud.

I would like to send a notification after not receiving any data for something like 10 minutes.  Can my cloud function have a re-settable trigger that would send me a notification if it doesn't get reset by my IoT device checking in within that time?  How do I create this delay?

I would prefer not to pay for the idle time.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing Cloud Functions well, my initial thought would be to use Task Queues on the App Engine.

On each incoming request from your device, you could enqueue a task with an eta of X minutes. When the task runs, it would check to see if any data has been written in the past X minutes. If not it would send a notification, and potentially queue up a fresh task to check again.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/

My assumption here is that you can access the data written by your cloud function from an App Engine application.